# Is it possible to programmatically make an optical click?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'Ve got a winform application where specific Buttons should be visibly pressed whenever a specific key is pressed.

Capturing the key is not so much a Problem, but I did not find a method that allowed me to make it visible that a specific button as been "pressed".
(Even with button1.PerformClick() there was no visualization of the "click").

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Control.Select()` to activate the control.